# implementing google spreadsheet data in polymer 1.0 chart element

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement data from my google spreadsheet into a google-chart element of polymer 1.0.

Is there a simple way to define the source of the data?
I do not want to use cols and rows since my spreadsheet is updating itself frequently.

What I would like is to use something like the data=' ' object to define the url of the spreadsheet and also the range, e.g. C3:C8.

But the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart) say i should use a .json format, and I do not know how to get that from google spreadsheet.

This is what I am using:

```
<google-chart type='line' options='{"title":"Line Chart"}' data=''></google-chart>
```

Is it possible to use the url and range of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to use `<iron-ajax>` and serve the data as content from your Google Apps Script `doGet()` function hosted by your spreadsheet. Assign the returned data content to a property in your custom element. Then bind your `data` attribute to that property.

You can pass the range variable as parameters in your `<iron-ajax>` call that you read in using `doGet(params)`.